# Why is PHP showing dates with 2014-01-01 as Jan 2013

Tags: php, date

I'm running into a strange issue that is specific only to dates in my database that are 2014-01-01. I'm reformatting the date, but PHP is displaying them as being JAN 13. All the other dates are displaying okay for different months. How is this possible?

My function:

```
public function exp_date($date) {
    // Hide wrong dates
    if ($date == '0000-00-00' || $date == '1969-12-31') {
        $out = "";
    } else {
        $out = strtoupper(date('M y', strtotime($date)));
    }

    if ($out == 'DEC 69' || $out == 'JAN 70') {
        $out2 = "";
    } else {
        $out2 = $out;
    }
    return $out2;
}
```

Comment: `php -r "echo date('M y', strtotime('2014-01-01'));"` prints out `Jan 14` for me .. what is `$date`?

Comment: `var_dump(date('M y', strtotime("2014-01-01")));` gives me `string(6) "Jan 14"`

Comment: I get Jan 14 http://codepad.viper-7.com/24SSI9

Comment: `echo var_dump(strtoupper(date('M y', strtotime(2014-01-01))));` is now giving me `string(6) "FEB 13" `

Comment: @Tomanow strtotime expects a string! What you're doing is `strtotime(2012)`

Comment: Ah I messed up that var dump, but I was also passing date through the function twice which somehow messed it up.

Comment: @NicholasPickering 1970-01-01 is the Unix epoch, but time_t is allowed to be negative. Additionally, unixtime is UTC, (time_t)0 is Dec 31, 19:00 EST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your call to `strtotime`:

```
$out = strtoupper(date('M y', $date));
```